# Foreground service vs WorkManager. Which is better for downloading/uploading?

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager, foreground-service

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/background#recommended-immediate) they have mentioned that, *For tasks that should be executed immediately and need continued processing, even if the user puts the application in background or the device restarts, we recommend using WorkManager and its support for long-running tasks.*

But then [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#deferrable) they tell *WorkManager is not intended for work that requires immediate execution.*

Now I wanted download/upload some media in my app. Desired behaviour is that, when user clicks download, it should start downloading, and once finishes, it should display the image(for eg). If user navigates away from activity, then also the download should continue and finish, and when user reenters the activity in future, that image should be shown.

For now, I have implemented it inside `CoroutineScope(IO).launch`, which is bad. Now I am confused should I implement Android `Service` or Android's `WorkManager`. Also in this SO answer, they have mentioned that `WorkManager` is not behaving as intended in all devices. If this is the case even now, then using `WorkManager` may degrade UX. So which should I use?

Comment: No need for all that stuff. DownloadManager will just do it.

Comment: Ok, for uploading?